# JWplayer 6 Asynchronous tags not tracking videos

Tags: google-analytics, jwplayer

I'm having trouble tracking Jwplayer vids on a site using Google Analytics. I am currently using the Asynchronous tags. Thank you all in advance for your help.

GA:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-7585298-9']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
```

})();

jw player:

```
 jwplayer("container").setup({
    'flashplayer': '@Url.Content("~/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf")',
    'playlist': [{
        'file': '@Url.Content("~/Content/videos/td100/3_STEPbySTEP_1920x1080_uncompressed_1200Kbps_480p.mp4")',
        'image': '@Url.Content("~/Content/videos/optineb/started.png")',
        'title': 'Getting Started',
        'description': 'Getting Started With Your Tyvaso Inhalation System',
         ga:{
            idstring: "title",
            trackingObject: "_trackPageview"

        }
    },
```

Comment: Is that the complete code for the player?

Comment: Yes this is the complete code.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where this is running, as well?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with jw player, but according to their documentation, it looks like `trackingObject` should actually be `trackingobject`(All lowercase).